# Place label and combobox next each other

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have three Labels and Combobox.
See the demo.

[image]
Each label and corresponding Combobox sit next each other.

I use Grid to divide the row into several columns. Then put the Label and Combobox into each column. However they are not next each other even I set the `HorizontalAlignment = "Left"`.

If I set the margin to adjust the positions. It works out temperately. 
When I resize the user control, the shape changed. I want responsive UI but margin values are hard-coded.

And the first Label should be on the left by the requirement.
So what is the best way to do it?

**Edit for Code**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid Height="35">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="Label1:" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="3" />
    <Label Grid.Column="5" Content="Label2:" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="7" />
    <Label Grid.Column="9" Content="Label3:" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="11" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: show us your code pls!

Comment: @Elhamer, code was added.

Comment: You want no space between the `Label`and the `ComboBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `auto` for the Labels' columns  and `*` for the comboboxes ones:

```
 <Grid Height="35">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Label1:" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1"  Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="Label2:" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="3" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
    <Label Grid.Column="4" Content="Label3:" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="5" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
</Grid>
```

If you don't your comboboxes to fill the remaining space use `HorizantalAlignement`:

```
  <ComboBox Grid.Column="1"  Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```